# Haskell error Improperly terminated character constant

Tags: python, haskell, recursion

I'm trying to pass to haskell the following code but it gets me error Improperly terminated character constant in haskell. The code in python is already tested and is correc

```
    import System.IO
    funcion x n = funcionaux x n 1
    funcionaux x n k = if(k>n) then 2*k-1 else (2*k-1)-((x**k)´div´(funcion(x,n,(k+1)))
    main = do
    x <- readLn :: IO Double
    n <- readLn :: IO Int
    putStrLn (show(funcion x n))
```

The python code is

```
    def funcion(x,n,k):
        if k > n:
            return ((2*k)-1)
        else:
            return ((2*k)-1) - ((x**k)/funcion(x, n, (k+1)))

    print(funcion(1.3,7,1))
```

Comment: `div` should be between backticks: `\`div\``...

Comment: Count your parentheses, and don't separate function arguments with `,`. It's `funcion x n (k + 1)`, not `funcion(x,n,k+1)`.

Comment: it is the python code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... Haskell is not so simple like python and it requires thoughtful study.

Working code looks like:

```
import System.IO

funcionaux x n k = if(k>n)
                then 2*k-1
                else (2*k-1)-((x^k) `div` (funcionaux x n (k+1)) )
main = do
 x <- readLn :: IO Int
 n <- readLn :: IO Int
 putStrLn (show (funcionaux x n 1))
```

And some notes:

1. for infix use `operator` not 'operator';
2. ** and ^ for different types;
3. `div` and / for different types too;
4. during a function call the arguments are passed without commas;
5. and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You want backticks (which indicate an infix use of a prefix function) around `div`, not single quotes (which indicate character constants, hence the error). That is, you should use `` `div` `` where you use `'div'`.

Comment: Alexis Still does not give me the code and I get error prog.hs: 4: 1: error:
    Parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) on line 4 
I already corrected the div error

Answer (score 1):

You are opening 4 parentheses and closing 3.

Here's a suggestion for reformatting your code. I also made `funcionaux` recursive as it should be.

You might have more errors to fix, this was untested.

```hs
import System.IO
funcion x n = funcionaux x n 1
funcionaux x n k = if k>n 
   then 2*k - 1 
   else 2*k - 1 - ((x**k) `div` funcionaux x n (k+1))
main = do
   x <- readLn :: IO Double
   n <- readLn :: IO Int
   putStrLn (show (funcion x n))
```